# Rails - JavaScript timed refresh for one view only

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app in which I would like only one view to be refreshed every five seconds.  I put the following in assets/javascripts/application.js

```
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  timedRefresh(5000);
});
```

However this will cause every view to be refreshed every five seconds.  How could I make this JavaScript apply to only one view?

(using Rails 3.2.5)

Comment: Rewrite `timedRefresh()` to pull in the new data and apply it to the part of the page you want instead of just reloading.

Comment: that would be a lot more complicated thought, wouldn't it?  making AJAX call, parsing JSON, creating DOM elements...

Comment: Oh I see what you're going for now... I thought you wanted to refresh part of the page, not a particular view. The simplest solution might be to just throw this in your view's JavaScript assets. Or follow something like @Turd Ferguson's answer.

Comment: I don't think I have JavaScript assets specific to my view, do I?  The only path with JavaScript assets that I know of is app/assets/javascripts and these apply to my entire application

Comment: Maybe you don't; depends on how you've got things set up. In any case, it's pretty easy to conditionally include a JavaScript asset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your JS in application.js you can simply check for the presence of a specific element and act accordingly. For example:

**some_vew.html.erb**

```
<div id = "refreshable">
    <!-- So on and so forth... -->
</div>
```

**application.js**

```
$(function() {

    // function timeRefresh()...

    if ($('#refreshable').length) {
        timedRefresh(5000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the  tag in the bottom of your view.

**some_view.html.erb**

```
...
contents
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  Put javascript code here...
</script>
```

This will make this script only available to someview.html.erb. The application.js makes the script global.

Comment: i have slight preference for the other solution just because they say its best to separate your javascript into a separate file